Ghidra and IDA addresses not aligned
I'm loading the same binary to both ghidra and IDA. When looking at main(), here's what both of them show:
ghidra
                             undefined main()
             undefined         AL:1           <RETURN>
             undefined4        Stack[-0x18]:4 local_18                                XREF[2]:     004005f6(W), 
                                                                                                   00400609(R)  
             undefined1        Stack[-0x58]:1 local_58                                XREF[1]:     004005fd(*)  
             undefined4        Stack[-0x5c]:4 local_5c                                XREF[1]:     004005e5(W)  
             undefined8        Stack[-0x68]:8 local_68                                XREF[1]:     004005e8(W)  

IDA
.text:00000000004005DD main            proc near               ; DATA XREF: _start_c+19↑o
.text:00000000004005DD
.text:00000000004005DD var_60          = qword ptr -60h
.text:00000000004005DD var_54          = dword ptr -54h
.text:00000000004005DD var_50          = byte ptr -50h
.text:00000000004005DD var_10          = dword ptr -10h

My question is: There's a difference of 8h between the offsets that each of the tools assign to the four variables - var_10 local_18, var_50 local_58, var_54 local_5c, var_60 local_68. I'm new to this, and from what I understand these are the offsets from the current stack pointer (RBP). What's the explanation to this? Given that it's the exact same binary, shouldn't all stack frames look exactly the same?
Additional information:
Later in the disassembly, ghidra shows the following line:
LEA        RAX=>local_58,[RBP + -0x50]
ghidra interpreted that RAX will hold the value of the variable local_58, following the LEA command from [RBP + -0x50]. How does this make sense, knowing that local_58 is offset by Stack[-0x58]:1 local_58?

"shouldn't all stack frames look exactly the same?" That's assuming the definition of a stack frame is the same between the two (as you said, offset from RBP). Obviosuly it is not. I know IDA defines stack base this way, so that STACK+0 is at the end of saved registers and just before local variables area. I'm guessing Ghidra is defining stack base at the entry RSP instead, so that saved registers are accounted in the stack (I guess RBP is the only saved register, so RBP==entryRSP-8, so local_58 is RBP-0x50 but it is also entryRSP-0x58).
